# SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Sign-in attempt prevented

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send email by phpmailer class.But i see this problem : `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.`

And in my gmail account i see a mail : `sign in attempt prevented`

### I am using this credentials :

```
function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
{                       
    require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
    $mail->Port       = 465;             
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Username="mymail@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password="password";            
    $mail->SetFrom('mymail@gmail.com','Coding Cage');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("mymail@gmail.com","Coding Cage");
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->Send();
}
```

Soemthing might be wrong or how i can provide permission as there is a message in my inbox : `Sign-in attempt prevented`

Comment: Well, your authentication fails. Nothing we can help with that.

Comment: Why not just use the IsMail function? This uses php mail and needs no authentication.

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer; [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Then base your code on the gmail examples provided, and read the troubleshooting guide which tells you exactly how to deal with gmail auth.

Answer (score 1):

Like what @Synchro said, you are using the old version of PHPMailer. Use the latest [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

You also mentioned that an email `Sign in attempt prevented` landed in your inbox. Try clicking on `Review your devices now` and there should be a button or link that says `Allow this sign in attempt` or similar. Then, try to run the code again to see if it works.

If not, well, if you have 2FA turned on in your Google account, try turning it off.

Hope it helps :)